# How to I delete items with onclick in firebase database?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a lot of issues trying to delete items off of my firebase database with the checkbox onclick but it is not working.

I am able to get the data onto firebase database and I am able to remove it from the HTML with the onclick at the bottom using $(this).remove but I can't get that to be mimicked in firebase.

```
  // Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDZwIxXFNk928XzjMRZ6bpXVkeuEMbwIUI",
authDomain: "in-the-know-a0b16.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://in-the-know-a0b16.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "in-the-know-a0b16",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "447330895711"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//create a variable to reference the database
var database = firebase.database();

//initialize value
var todos = "";
var todoclose = $("<button>");
todoclose.addClass("checkbox");
todoclose.text("☑");

$(document).ready(function() {
// user clicked on the add button in the to-do field add that text into the 
//to-do text
 $('#add-todo').on('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();

 //values per text box
  todos = $("#todo-input").val().trim();

 //test values from textbox
 console.log(todos);

//code for handling the push
database.ref().push({
 todos: todos
 });

});

//firebase watcher
database.ref().limitToLast(1).on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    todos = snap.child("todos").val();

 //prepend values to html
 $("<div/>", {
  "class": "to-do-item"
   }).append([todoclose, todos]).appendTo($(".col-4"));

 //to remove item from checklist
 $(document.body).on("click", ".to-do-item",function() {
   $(this).remove();

  });
   });
});

  });
```

HTML

```
                <div class ="col-4">
                <form role = "form">
                    <div class = "form-group row">
                    <div class = "To-Do-List">
                        <label for="todo-input">Add Your To Do List Here:</label>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="todo-input" type = "text">
                    </div><div class="button">
                        <button class ="btn btn-danger" id="add-todo" type="submit">Add</button></div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <tbody id = "table_body">
            </tbody>
```

Comment: u need to have a endpoint defined for the deletion on firebase. just call that endpoint and u will be able to perform deletion. Do a google search on REST API.

Comment: You don't need to use the REST API. You can just call the database wrapper;

`database.ref('/todos').remove();` Would remove the whole node `/todos`. You can remove a single key with `database.ref('/todos/-key1').remove()`.

Comment: so something like this?   $(document.body).on("click", ".to-do-item",function() {
   $(this).remove();
   database.ref('/todos/-key1').remove()
  });